# CodeIgniter 2.0: Unknown column ' ' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I'm new in CI 2.0, when it come error like this:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'lap_jenis' in 'where clause'
```

SELECT * FROM (`laporankebijakan`) WHERE `lap_type` = 0 AND `lap_jenis` = 0 ORDER BY `upd_dt` desc LIMIT 10

My controller was:

```
public function posts($lap_type_id=0, $lap_jenis_id=0, $offset = 0) {
    if(!$this->session->userdata('login')) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Please Relogin.');
        redirect('login');
        exit;
    }

    if(!$this->module_auth->read) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->module_auth->msg_read);
        redirect('warning');
    }


    $uri_segment = 4;
    $num_links   = 5;
    $limit       = 10;
    $offset      = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);

    $posts = $this->laporan_kebijakan_model->get_paged_list($limit, $offset, $lap_type_id, $lap_jenis_id);

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['first_url']   = '0';
    $config['base_url']    = site_url('kebijakan/posts/'.$lap_type_id);
    $config['total_rows']  = $this->laporan_kebijakan_model->count_all($lap_type_id, $lap_jenis_id);
    $config['per_page']    = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
    $config['num_links']   = $num_links;
    $config['cur_tag_open']  = '<span class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = '<center><div class="pagination">'.$this->pagination->create_links().'</div></center>';

    $data['current']    = 'kebijakan';
    $data['lap_type_id']= $lap_type_id;
            $data['lap_jenis_id']= $lap_jenis_id;
    $data['posts']      = $posts;

    $this->load->view('vkebijakan_admin',$data);
}
```

and my model are:

```
    function get_paged_list($limit = 10, $offset = 0, $jenis=0){
    $this->db->where('status', $jenis);
    $this->db->order_by('create_date','desc');
    return $this->db->get($this->tbl, $limit, $offset)->result();
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Does your table have a column called `lap_jenis`?

Comment: You should be checking your database structure, not your code. You answer means, literally, that your table 'laporankebijakan'. does not contain a column named 'lap_jenis'.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your table "laporankebijakan" has no column like "lap_jenis". Create a column named "lap_jenis" in that table. Hopefully the error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your table 'laporankebijakan' may not have a column named 'lap_jenis' .Check your table and double check the column name.